# Accessing client context in a Lambda function via API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I've created a Lambda function, and connected it to an API Gateway endpoint. My users are authenticating using Facebook via Cognito (so, obviously using a Federated Identity Pool). In my iOS app, I am able to authenticate properly, receive a Cognito Id back, and also properly execute my Lambda function by way of API Gateway.

Where I'm stuck now is attempting to access the user's identity in my lambda. I understand from other threads & the AWS docs that I should use able to access the identity via `context.identity.cognitoIdentityId` in JS. However, the context is always null.

Further digging suggested that the context is passed in the X-Amz-Client-Context header -- when I look at packets for the API Gateway call, I do not see that header being passed through. I am using the automatically generated SDK (ObjC) from Gateway for my endpoints.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using a template other than the passthrough template in the method request?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The header is not being generated by the client SDK anyways, so I think it's more an issue here. Or is the X-Amz-Client-Context added in by API Gateway automatically?

Comment: The `X-Amz-Client-Context` header is supposed to be added by the mobile SDK automatically and then processed by API Gateway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize for the confusion. You have 2 options for getting this value into your lambda function:

1. By passing via API Gateway. If you are using the Lambda Proxy, it should already be available in `event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId`.
2. By enabling **use caller credentials** in your integration. If you use this method, you will also need to add `lambda:Invoke` permissions to your Cognito role.

Comment: Thanks. I finally got that to works. I ended up using option 1. Bob, is there a best practices doc out there for working with an API Gateway + Lambda + Cognito setup? Cobbling together how to get this to work was exhausting.

Comment: @Vickram we are looking to add support for Cognito as part of [AWS SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) which should help gluing all the services together.

Comment: You do have to be sure to enable `useIAMAuth` for option 1 to work.